# Date formatting in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date: SAT 29 JUN 19. How do I convert it into date format e.g. 29 JUN 19 using Excel-VBA. Thanks.

By using this code:
`wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1) = CDate(Format(RemoveWkDay, "DD MMM YY"))`
The output is: 29/06/2019

Comment: What's the value of RemoveWkDay? And isn't the output what you wanted - A date?

Comment: In this example the value of RemoveWkDay is 29 JUN 19 which is in general format.I want to convert it into date but preserve the same format DD MM YY.The cell A1 to A30 contains date for the month of June 2019 in an random order.My program will sort it out in an asecending order.

Comment: You mean DD MMM YY. Check answer below

Comment: Exchange CDate and Format: Start with CDate first and then do the Format.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments above, you can use:
`wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A30").NumberFormat = "dd mmm yy;@"`
To do that for the whole column, use `Range("A:A")` instead.

In fact, you do not need VBA for this. You can just set that string as the custom format in the Sheet.

Comment: @Asger, Yes, I did. Thank you. I have amended answer. OP hasn't bothered to say if it solved the problem..lol